# (FileObserver) как правильно отследить перенос файла в файловой системе на Android?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно отслеживать события в определенной папке и её под каталогах рекурсивно. Для этих целей я нашел только FileObserver, но как я выяснил, он не отслеживает события рекурсивно по всем папкам. Для отслеживания рекурсивно предлагают подобные решения.
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Example/course/com_toraleap_collimator_utilRecursiveFileObserver_java.htm

Но при переносе папки или файла возникает проблема. Во время переноса генерируется два события MoveFrom и MoveTo и насколько я понимаю что нет ни какой гарантии что между этим событиями не произойдет какое то третье событие. FileObeserve возвращает только путь и тип события.  MoveFrom - по сути мы имеем информацию о том что файл который лежат по такому то пути был куда то перенесен. MoveTo - был перенесен файл который теперь лежит по этому пути. При этом эти события возвращаются разными экземплярами FileObeserve.

Получается что если переносы файлов будет происходит одновременно в нескольких каталогах с одинаковыми именами файлов, станет непонятно как отследить перенос файла. Можно различать файлы по хешу, но такой трюк не проделаешь с папкой.

Вообщем не понятно как бороться с такой ситуацией? Возможно есть более простые способы её решить?